# inserting divs into the dom using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

im trying to insert a new div into the DOM with an id of "app"

```
var new_div = document.createElement("div");
var app_div = document.getElementById("app");
document.body.insertBefore(new_div, app_div);​
```

this gives me an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null

but i don't know why?

Comment: Are you able to use jQuery or are you wanting to do it without using an additional library?

Comment: i don't mind using jquery, but where do i start?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zkrCR/ (inspect the doc to see the div). Where is the code in your document?

Comment: @Kane - There's no need to load jQuery for something this basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code to window.onload handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var new_div = document.createElement("div");
    var app_div = document.getElementById("app");
    document.body.insertBefore(new_div, app_div);
}
```

---

Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uJafg/).

Answer (score 0):

Except that it would be better wrapped in onload() as suggested by Igor, don't you want to add new_div to the document first?

```
document.body.insertBefore(new_div, document.body.firstChild);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use jquery document.ready event